# ControlBuilder and parsechildrenattribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is purpose of ControlBuilder Class in asp.net mentioned here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlbuilder.aspx) and parsechildren class mentioned here(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.parsechildrenattribute.aspx). I have read the links but I didnt fully understand their purpose. Can someone please send me other examples of these two classes and their usage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, every control on a page is associated with a default control builder class. A control builder works side by side with the page parser and helps to analyze the markup for the control and to build all the necessary child controls. The control builder class is responsible for handling any child markup element that the main tag of a control contains. The base class for control builders is ControlBuilder .

The default ControlBuilder class adds a child control to the Controls collection for every nested element it encounters within the control's tags. In addition, it creates literal controls for the text located between nested control tags. Custom controls are processed by the default control builder. If you don't like the way in which the ControlBuilder class works, replace the default control builder with a custom one. In most cases, you'll use a custom control builder if the control has a complex layout or contains child tags that require ad hoc parsing.

For more detail follow this-

http://http.www.flylib.com/books/en/2.371.1.153/1/